# How to use custom field for search in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i have a model and is registered to the admin and i have used custom field to display in the list

```
class ReportsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def investment(self, inst):
        return models.OrderDetail.objects.filter(user=inst.user).distinct().count()

    list_display = ['investment']
    search_fields = ['investment']
```

i want to search using the `investment` field in django admin but always getting `Cannot resolve keyword 'investment' into field.` choices are the Model fields.

is there any way by which i can search using the `investment` field?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In software, anything is possible... SMH at the accepted answer. You have to override `get_search_results`.

```
from django.db.models import Count

class ReportsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def investment(self, inst):
        return models.OrderDetail.objects.filter(user=inst.user).distinct().count()

    list_display = ['investment']
    search_fields = ['investment']

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        # search_term is what you input in admin site
        search_term_list = search_term.split(' ')  #['apple','bar']

        if not any(search_term_list):
            return queryset, False

        if 'investment' in search_term_list:
           queryset = OrderDetail.objects.annotate(
               user_count=Count('user')
           ).filter(user_count__gte=search_term_list['investment'])

        return queryset, False
```

Comment: This is the right answer, as discussed in the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not allowed:

[ModelAdmin.search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields)

> Set search_fields to enable a search box on the admin change list
>   page. This should be set to a list of field names that will be
>   searched whenever somebody submits a search query in that text box.
>
> These fields should be some kind of text field, such as **CharField** or
>   **TextField**. You can also perform a related lookup on a ForeignKey or
>   ManyToManyField with the lookup API “follow” notation:

You don't have such a field at all (never mind that the field has to be a TextField or CharField). What you actually have is a method in your admin class, which cannot be searched at the database level. Ie what's in the search_fields translates to `like '%search_term%'` type queries executed at the db.

Comment: so can't you say for example `^bla` to search for values starting with "bla"? I mean, isn't it possible to specify some shortcuts in the search box that the user can try?